# Using varlist multiple times in Stata

Tags: list, stata

I have three variables varA, varB and varC.
I attempted to first replace "missing" with NA in all three variables then add a label to all three variables.

First I replaced "missing" with NA:

```
local mylist1 varA-varC
foreach v1 of varlist `mylist1'  { 
   replace `v1'="NA" if `v1' =="missing"
}
```

Now if I want to call the list again to add the same label to all three variables:

```
foreach v1 of varlist `mylist1' {
   label var `v1' "testvaraible"
}
```

but I will get an error message saying :

```
varlist required
```

Could anyone explain why I can't recall the list?

Answer (score 1):

For your first example, this would be legal syntax if the variables concerned were all string:

```
local mylist1 varA-varC
foreach v of varlist `mylist1'  { 
    replace `v' = "NA" if `v' == "missing"
}
```

Notice the different punctuation for referring to a local macro (different left and right quotation marks) and the difference in placing braces.

It is difficult even to work out what you want in your second example, but the loop is over differing values of a local macro `v` which you never refer to inside the loop. Also, depending on the definition of the unspecified local macro `testvaraible` [sic], it is still puzzling why you would label three variables identically.

You may need to be much more explicit about your data and exactly what you want if this does not answer the question. In particular, we can't see definitions for local macros `v1` and `testvaraible`.

Comment: thanks for your comments.  I have edited my question and hope it makes more sense now.  Bascially, i am just not sure why I cannot use the varlist again when I want to give the same label to all three variables.  Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your revision, but almost the same comments arise. We can't see the definition of `testvaraible`. If that is defined in a different place, it won't be visible to your code: that's what `local` means. The punctuation using `' '` remains wrong for local macros in your second example.

Comment: I have made more changes now - does this make sense now?  In the second loop, I simply want to label all three variables as "testvariable".  Sorry for the confusion as I have just started using Stata.

Comment: @William Lisowski has guessed what you want. Between us, the typo "testvaraible" has also been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this discussion after the edits made in response to the discussion around the previous answer. At this point, copying the code as it now stands in the original post, the problem has apparently been corrected. Hate to post this as an answer, but it's apparently too long for a comment.

```
. set obs 1
obs was 0, now 1

. generate str8 varA = "a"

. generate str8 varB = "missing"

. generate str8 varC = "c"

. local mylist1 varA-varC

. foreach v1 of varlist `mylist1'  { 
  2.    replace `v1'="NA" if `v1' =="missing"
  3. }
(0 real changes made)
(1 real change made)
(0 real changes made)

. foreach v1 of varlist `mylist1' {
  2.    label var `v1' "testvariable"
  3. }

. list, clean noobs

    varA   varB   varC  
       a     NA      c  

. describe

Contains data
  obs:             1                          
 vars:             3                          
 size:            24                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
varA            str8    %9s                   testvariable
varB            str8    %9s                   testvariable
varC            str8    %9s                   testvariable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:  
     Note:  dataset has changed since last saved

.
```

Comment: Many thanks for presenting this in a much clearer way.  My question is why do i get "varlist required" after 2nd loop even though I followed every step of your code?

Comment: I've just noticed that iif I run everything together there will be no error, however if I run it line by line, the error message "varlist required" would appear.

Comment: I'm guessing that when you run it "line by line" you have actually created the entire program in the do-file editor, and then are have selected a group of lines and run them. When you do that, Stata creates a temporary file containing the selected lines, then submits that file as a do-file, as your log will show. The local macros created by the code within a do-file are local to the running of that do-fille and vanish when the do-file is exited, thus are undefined when you submit the second part of your code.

Comment: yes, I think that is exactly the problem.  Is there any way to overcome this issue so that I can still run it line by line but stata won't "forget" the varlist?

Comment: Technically, you could use a global macro rather than a local macro, but that is inadvisable for any number of reasons. The do-file editor's ability to run a few lines at a time doesn't really interact well with local macros. I expect it was meant to allow the user to test relatively straightforward sequences of Stata commands, rather than to develop more complicated logic. You could copy groups of lines from the do-file editor and paste them into the command window, which will accept multiple lines of input (I think you have to hit return after the paste).